# I Assigned a Variable but it Says I Did Not

Tags: python, windows, variable-assignment, python-3.5, unassigned-variable

Note: I am using Python 3.5
I just started creating a part two to a text based game I made, and here is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
import random

def game():
    randomIp = random.randint(10, 999)

    def tutorial():
        global randomIp

        print('Hello.')
        print(randomIp + '.' + randomIp + '.' + randomIp + '.' + randomIp)
```

The problem that kept coming up was:

```
File "C:\Users\Anony\Desktop\SICCr4k2BrokeFold\SICCr4k2Broke.py", line 18, in tutorial
  print(randomIp + '.' + randomIp + '.' + randomIp + '.' + randomIp)
NameError: name 'randomIp' is not defined
```

I don't know what's up. I have the global put into `tutorial()` and it doesn't have an error for saying `randomIp` isn't defined in the command `global randomIP` only for `print(randomIp + '.' + randomIp + '.' + randomIp + '.' + randomIp)`. Does anyone know what the problem is? And if I wanted a different random number to be printed after each `"."`. What would the code be for that? I would like it so that it would print out something like `23.321.43.23`. A completely different number after each period.

Comment: A "global" is a module-level variable. You're defining it in an enclosing scope, but not module level; thus, it's **not** actually a global for you.

Comment: because `tutorial()` is inside of your `game()` module level, you dont need to use `global` keyword

Comment: @RNar: `tutorial()` does not have `randomIp=` in it.  `global randomIp` should not be used in it at all regardless of where `randomIp` or `tutorial()` are actually defined.

Comment: unrelated: to print a random IPv4, you could use `print(ipaddress.IPv4Address(random.getrandbits(32)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a local variable, but then you try to access a global of the same name.

You could simply omit the `global` keyword.

```
def game():
    randomIp = ...
    def tutorial():
        print(randomIp + ...)
```

Note that this will only work if you don't *assign* `randomIp` inside `tutorial()`, otherwise you will need the `nonlocal` declaration:

```
def game():
    randomIp = ...
    def tutorial():
        nonlocal randomIp
        randomIp += 5 # counts as assignment
        print(randomIp + ...)
```

Also note that it's more typical in python to use `.format()` instead of `+` when working with strings...

```
# This works
print('{0}.{0}.{0}.{0}'.format(randomIp))

# This does not work
# print(randomIp + '.' + randomIp + '.' + randomIp + '.' + randomIp)
```

This is because you can't add an integer to a string in Python.  In some other languages, this will result in automatic conversion.  In Python, it will just result in an error.

### Generating a random IP

This will generate a random IP address from a valid /8 block, skipping the `127` localhost block, multicast blocks, and whatnot.  It may generate addresses which are broadcast addresses, depending on the netmask.

```
def randomIp():
    x = random.randint(1, 222)
    if x == 127:
        x += 1
    return '{}.{}.{}.{}'.format(
        x,
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255))
```

Of course, you shouldn't actually use the IP address for anything.

Comment: If I wanted a different random number to be printed after each `"."`. What would the code be for that? I would like it so that it would print out something like 23.321.43.23. A completely different number after each period @DietrichEpp

Comment: @JohnAntonioAnselmo: You'd need a function, then.

Comment: So how would I replace `print(randomIp + '.' + randomIp + '.' + randomIp + '.' + randomIp)` with that?. Do I just call `randomIp()` whenever I need one, and it will list something like 32.34.423.34, or something like that? @DietrichEpp

Comment: Yes, it will return a string like that.

Comment: It outputs an Ip with single quotes, is there any way to take away the single quotes? @DietrichEpp

Comment: It doesn't output anything, because there is no `print()` call.  It *returns* a string.  The string does not contain any quote marks at all.  However, if you evaluate an expression in the REPL that evaluates to a string, the string will be passed to `repr()` before printing, which will add quote marks.  You are probably seeing the quote marks from the REPL.